# How and can you create test data for espresso? (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-espresso

Im using RecyclerView and room for my app. 
I started writing the ui tests using Espresso, and for example when i display the main activity a recyclerView is shown with data from the database. Is there a way to use test data for espresso? or create a test database?

Comment: Yes, and it's highly encouraged to only rely on test/mocked data for tests. How you do it depends on your app setup; for example, if you use a dependency management framework (e.g. Dagger) to provide your database and its data, then you can wire your test app to be injected with that mocked database.